# How to construct empty Array list in Json using Rest Assured

Tags: json, api, selenium, automation, rest-assured

I am serializing the Json from POJO class. I want to send empty array in Request but when i pass null or empty value to the properties in pojo class, i am getting [""] in array list instead of []

```
Expected:  "Key": []

But I am getting: "Key":[""]
```

My pojo:

```
public class Sample {

    private List<String> Key=null;
}
```

Test data builder class:

```
Sample s = new Sample();
s.Key = ""; // Even if i give null here, i am getting null at the json payload.
```

Pls suggest ways to construct an empty array for Key as below.

```
{
"Key": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize new ArrayList, like this.

```
Sample s = new Sample();
s.Key = new ArrayList<>();
```